# URL directs to router admin page

Tags: apache, router

I am using no-ip service for dynamic DNS and port forwarding also done, router admin page is showing up instead of web server when I type URL . I am using Huawei HG655b router and Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

The router may not have the capability of allowing incoming requests to go through it on port 80. Unfortunately I can't say exactly what to do since the manual for your router is very basic. But have a look to see if there are settings which allow you to:

- Disable access from outside your network to the admin page
- Change the port that the admin page is served from

Comment: I have no idea how to disable access to admin page but I changed "Listen" port no 80 to 8181 still its not working

Comment: It might not be possible to do. I suggest you contact the manufacturer